# State Management in Angular without using Libraries

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I'm using a data table (using Material Data Tables) in my application and I want to build a simple example where I'm saving the state of the thee filters without using libraries such as NGRX etc.

My issue is small enough not to use an entire library at this point; what are ways that I am able to do this?

Comment: Use a [standard angular service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)?  If you need something more you don't have to use NGRX, there are plenty of other, less involved state plugins as well (Having used NGRX and moved to NGXS.. it was insanely nice).

Answer (score 0):

Super simple state utility can be like something below.

```
this.state = {}
this.setState = (key,value) => this.state={...this.state,key:value}
```

you can put that in a singleton share service.

Answer (score 0):

You can have simple state service using rxjs

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StateService {
    private _state$ = new BehaviorSubject({});

    dispatchUserLoggedStatus(status) {
        this._state$.next({
            ...this._state$.value,
            isLogged: status
        });
    }

    get state$() {
        return this._state$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

The point of using librraries is when you need extra features

Answer (score 0):

this is a good solution by using **rxjs-observable-store**, the The store’s state is a BehaviorSubject, you can subscribe to the state updates in your components

```
this.store.state$.subscribe(state => {
  // Logic to execute on state update
});
```

or using

```
this.store.state;
```